# Geometry solution involving complex numbers from USAMO

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers, contest-math, analytic-geometry

> Quadrilateral $AP BQ$ is inscribed in circle $ω$ with $∠P = ∠Q = 90^{\circ}$
> and $AP = AQ < BP$. Let $X$ be a variable point on segment $P Q$. Line
> $AX$ meets $ω$ again at $S$ (other than $A$). Point $T$ lies on arc
> $AQB$ of $ω$ such that $XT$ is perpendicular to $AX$. Let $M$ denote
> the midpoint of chord $ST$. As $X$ varies on segment $P Q$, show that
> $M$ moves along a circle. (USAMO 2015/P2)

Okay so, I'm studying geometry from the book EGMO by Evan Chan and this was a practice problem. The solution in the back of the book is the same as the one from Evan's 2015 USAMO notes. I am pretty much a newbie with geometry with complex numbers.

Everything in his solution makes sense apart from this one part. Could somebody please explain that? Also was this question supposed to be trivial using complex geometry? (Just askin ).

The solution is as follows:

> Toss on the complex unit circle with $a = −1$, $b = 1$, $z=-\frac{1}{2}$. Let $s$ and $t$ be on the unit circle. We claim $z$ is the center. It follows from standard formulas that  $x =\frac{1}{2}(s
>  + t − 1 +\frac{s}{t})$
>
> thus,
>
> $4 \cdot \mathrm{Re}(x) + 2 = s + t +\frac{1}{s}+\frac{1}{t}+\frac{t}{s}+\frac{s}{t}$
>
> which depends only on $P $ and $Q$, and not on $X$. Thus,
>
> $4 \left| z − \dfrac{s + t}{2}\right|^2= |s + t + 1|^2 = 3 + (4 \cdot \mathrm{Re}(x )+ 2)$
>
> does not depend on $X$.

Well I guess I get that $\mathrm{Re}(x)$ refers to the real part of $x$ but where does the quantity $4\cdot \mathrm{Re}(x)+2$ come from?

Also in the next equation there is $4 \left|z − \dfrac{s + t}{2}\right|^2$. Where does this come from? And why does not being dependent on $X$ mean done? Please forgive my stupidity in case this is all extremely trivial stuff.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: For reference here is a link to the solutions: https://web.evanchen.cc/exams/USAMO-2015-notes.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The goal is to show that the locus of the midpoint of $ST$ is a circle. The equation $ 4 | z - \frac{ s + t } { 2} | ^2 = A $ would then mean that the midpoint of $ST$, represented by $ \frac{ s+ t } { 2 } $ lies on a circle of radius $ \sqrt{\frac{ A}{4}} $ about the point $z$. Hence, it suffices to show that $A$ is a constant (independent of the point $X$ chosen).

1. To prove this, Evan claims that $ Z =( - \frac{1}{2},0) $ is the center. (You could guess this from the construction, or force it out based on the calculations below.) Setting $ z = - \frac{1}{2}$ , we get $ 4 | z - \frac{ s + t } { 2} | ^2  = |s + t + 1|^2$. (This is just arithmetic)
2. Now, because $ s\overline{s} = 1$, hence $ \overline{s} = \frac{1}{s}$. Likewise, $ \overline{t} = \frac{1}{t} $. Hence, $ |s+t+1| ^2 = (s+t+1 ) ( \overline{s+t+1} ) = (s+t+1) ( \frac{1}{s} + \frac{1}{t} + 1 ) = 3 + \frac{s}{t} + \frac{t}{s} + s + t + \frac{1}{s} + \frac{1}{t}. $
3. Substituting $4 Re x + 2 = s + t +\frac{1}{s}+\frac{1}{t}+\frac{t}{s}+\frac{s}{t}$ (verified below) into the above, we get $ | s+t+1|^2 = 4 Re x + 2 + 3 $.
4. Notice that $PQ$ is a vertical line, and $X$ is a point on $PQ$, so the real part of $X$ is a constant.
5. Putting all of this together, we do truly get $ 4 | z - \frac{x+t}{2} |^2 = |s+t+1|^2 = 4Rex + 5= A$, so the locus is a circle.

---

Using that $x = \frac{1}{2} ( s + t - 1 + \frac{s}{t})$, $ \overline{s} = \frac{1}{s}$, and $ \overline{t} = \frac{1}{t} $, hence $$ 4 Re x = 2(x + \overline{x}) = ( s + t - 1 + \frac{s}{t} ) + (\overline{ s + t - 1 + \frac{s}{t} } ) = s + t - 1 + \frac{s}{t} + \frac{1}{s} + \frac{1}{t} - 1 + \frac{t}{s} . $$

Note: I did not come up with $x = \frac{1}{2} ( s + t - 1 + \frac{s}{t})$ when I first stated on this. I only knew about it from your writeup. While I can prove it having known it, I'm not confident that I would have come up with it independently.

---

Yes, this question ends up being quite direct once we use complex numbers. The "hard" part was

1. Guessing the center $z$ but even that wasn't that bad if you backtracked from the available information, and
2. Finding the relationship  $x = \frac{1}{2} ( s + t - 1 + \frac{s}{t})$

Part of the reason why complex numbers makes the solution trivial than other techniques is that the relationship  $x = \frac{1}{2} ( s + t - 1 + \frac{s}{t})$ would be hard to express otherwise. E.g. If you saw it, how would you describe the relationship of these 3 points? Even using vectors (which is sometimes a close substitute for complex numbers), this is more complicated than most would like to deal with.

Comment: Wow fantastic explanation. Taking a $z$ to be the center and showing that the" radius "infact stays constant and so forms a circle, this bit definitely seems pretty natural and obvious, what does not seem intuitive or obvious or clear is why did we choose to compute it in the first place. Seeing now that there is a very good way to link it with the other length and it being a constant completes the condition, it seems clear, but how would i have thought or realised that i should infact try and compute it? And that it will infact fit in very well and be a worthy investment of time?

Comment: What i really mean is i should have considered it for relating to the length being constant just because it itself is a constant ($Rex$)?? Or was there some reason for that? What would have been the backup plan then incase $Rex$ didnt fit in and did not solve the problem? What i mean from all these questions is ofc what can i take away from this question :).

Comment: Great questions that you're asking. It's good to see that you're thinking through the solution and trying to figure out how to apply it to other cases / extracting the crux of it. 1) This setup is very natural/intuitive. Once you decide to use complex numbers, it's one of the direct ways to show that the locus is a circle. As I mentioned, the hard part is guessing $z$, especially during a competition when you don't have access to graphing aids.

Comment: 2) The hard part (at least for me) is in relating points X, S, and T to each other. At first glance, I didn't get that equation. This writeup benefitted greatly from hindsight. 3) That the radius (IE $A$) is independent of $Re x$ is essentially what the question asks for, since $Re x$ is the (only?) invariant of points on $PQ$. The backup plan, would be to see if it's independent of $Re x$ when also subject to $|x| < 1$ (lying within the circle). IE Steps 1 and 2 are obvious. Step 3 was a "huh" to me because I didn't get the definition of $x$.

Comment: So basically invariance is actually what we are looking for when the question is about loci isn't it? Then, "Seeing that $Rex$ is infact the only invariant. And then after computing $|s+t+1|^2$, we see that we have a wierd equation in terms of $s4 and $t$. Since the only invariant is $Rex we once again look at it and realise that due to complex feet we can infact easily compute $x$ and since all the points are on the unit circle, the conjugate follows thereafter. Thus we now have $Rex$ after multiplying by 4 we see that infact it does match our original wierd expression!

Comment: So we simply substitute it in and since $Rex$ is constant, thus our radius is constant for all points and we are done."  This would have been the ideal situation isn't it? Also since we see multiple points on a single circle it obviously makes sense to try complex numbers isn't it? Or am i wrong in saying so? In the case i am not, then the question would infact be pretty trivial.

Comment: Fun fact : This is infact the first question i have attempted which uses the concept of a locus of points. Which is why i was practically clueless after deciding on the orientation of the circle ($PQ$ perpendicular to X since that puts more conjugates on the picture) and figuring out $x$. Yes so infact for questions involving locus invariance is infact exactly what we are looking for isn't it? To be able to show that the points which satisfy these conditions satisfy a constant relation.

Comment: 1) Prove locus using invariance - Not always, but often. Another way to prove locus is to show that the points have a bijective map, especially if inversion is involved 2) Yes, that $Re x$ is the only invariance motivates finding a formula for $Rex =  x + \bar{x}$. (Multiplying by 4 merely simplifies the arithmetic to reduce fractions.) 3) Algebraic methods like coordinate geometry, vectors, and complex numbers are useful for showing invariance.

Comment: 4) "since we see multiple points on a single circle it obviously makes sense to try complex numbers " -> I don't agree with this as written, can you elaborate? There's also a simple expression for points on a circle via coord geom and vectors. However, the reason why complex numbers works well is because of the formula for $z$, which doesn't have a simple equivalent in CG/V (yes, we could transform it, but it looks very ugly) 5) Def practice with more locus questions to get the hang of it: a) find the description of the locus, b) find a clean setup/relationship, and c) manipulate variables.

Comment: Hmm i get it will keep those tools in mind too. The logic behind tht sentence as that id read somewhere that complex numbers infact handles such conditions extremely well. Also, what do you think of barycentric coordinates? Are they worth it? Also, should i go over coordinate and barycentrics first or would it be better to start inversion? Seeing as i do have a lot of time before the actual imo and its selection rounds. Or should i start with something else entirely? What i mean is which ones are the most powerful useful and versatile tools/topics?

Comment: Learn what interests and excites you / Optimize towards your happiness. Inversion and Barcycentric coordinates are considered "specialized" tools, in the sense that while they could yield a solution to the problem, most problem committees would not use a problem if that was the only (reasonable) way to a solution. So, you might be able to save time (which is a good thing, like in this case), but that doesn't significantly increase the number of Olympiad problems that you can solve. (Arguably, complex numbers and vectors also belong to this category, but most people understand them better.)

Comment: Right, part of it is recognizing which setups lend well to which tools. It's similar to "when do we use coordinate geometry vs polar coordinates?". It is often better to have a deeper familiarity with a few tools, then a passing knowledge of many of them. I haven't come across a set of notes on complex numbers that details the multitude of ways to use them, and why it's ideal in those scenarios (but I haven't been aggressively looking).

Comment: Yeah no doubt inversion looks exciting as heck to me.  So soon i might jus start it. Well but saving time is important too isnt it? So we can lend more to the tougher problems? So its like finding the right balance between knowing the number of topics and expertise in them. Could you also help with olympiad combi? I mean how i should approach it? M currently reading thru otis excerpts by evan but well the difficulty progression of the questions isnt really straight and it wud be better if i had a slightly more broken down step by step progression of knowledge and question difficulty.

Comment: But at the same time i dont wish to sacrifice the compactness that otis excerpts book provides. Simple short and to the point and teaching good powerful tools in little time (not ALL the tools but some important ones which is a good start and ill surely learn more along the way).With these things in mind do u have suggestions for any handouts or combi books? A one whose pdf is not reasonably difficult to find id say as buying books and delivery is not what anybody wud like these days.  Though u may certainly ignore the last point while suggesting if the quality is high enough.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: OTIS excepts is a good place to start. Part of the difficulty is knowing what level of difficulty you are at / are comfortable with. Also try using the IMO compendium, work from the problems/short/longlist from the very start of the competition, till you get to a place where you can solve 1/4, maybe 2/5, but not 3/6. Scan through the solution to see what techniques they use (while avoid reading the solution too completely), then go read up on the techniques (search for olympiad notes) and think about how they could apply.

Comment: Hmmmm that seems like a good idea. However just going through questions of the compendium, the problem i feel ill have is ill always have to take an extra step to get more knowledge after or before a question (regarding topics ofc). Like otis excerpts n egmo its pretty simple u get some knowledge theory n then questions. Maybe not all of theory is there but atleast some and atleast familiarizes u with whats gon be there in the qeustions. And yes i can do decent counting questions however m very poor at olympiad combinatorics as well as basic stuff like expected values.

Comment: You cud consider me a person with exactly high school knowledge of combi( maybe slightly less).

Comment: Given that, for combinatorics you will need a lot more of the basics. Check out the wiki pages on Brilliant, especially those under [Counting](https://brilliant.org/discrete-mathematics/?subtopic=counting), Sets and Partitions, Probability, Recurrence Relations and [Advanced Discrete](https://brilliant.org/discrete-mathematics/?subtopic=advanced-combinatorics). I'd also recommend "Principles and Techniques in Combinatorics by Koh Khee Meng". I relied heavily on it 20 years ago (so there might be better texts out there now).

Comment: Hmm i see. Thanks a lot for your help sir. I wish you good health during these times :).